# Subtring and Substring index to split into two integers

Tags: mysql, split

I'm trying to split this hours into two different columns, I have the columns "hrs" and "mins"

For example, if the user enters `0.50` --- 0 should go to the "hrs" column, while 50 should go to the mins column.

I tried to use SUBSTRING_INDEX and SUBSTRING and it worked

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING("0.50", 3), ".", 2)
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING("0.50", 1), ".", 1)
```

and I got the output 0 and 50. so that's working, but what if the user will enter, 10.5 or 2.5 then it all becomes messed up.

How can I properly split it into 2 separate integers?

Thank you

Comment: You're on the right track.  This may ease your life: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Comment: Great!  Please post your answer and self-accept so future programmers may benefit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not explode?

```
$pizza = "05.500";

$pieces = explode(".", $pizza);

echo $pieces[0];
echo '/';
echo $pieces[1];
```